# ¿Cómo autentificarme en Azure Active Directory?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure, activedirectory

Hola tengo una aplicación web api en asp.net core 6.0, y nesecito autenticarme contra los usuarios  de Azure Active Directory.

Escribí este código pero no funciona, si alguien puede re factorizar mi código o crear uno que funcione correctamente seria genial, me devuelve el siguiente error:

*AADSTS50027: JWT token is invalid or malformed.\r\nTrace ID: a2a9117e-0135-4991-a32f-61991a810700\r\nCorrelation ID: accbd434-07ea-473c-9d60-2ebd2d5fccd6\r\nTimestamp: 2023-08-12 20:43:02Z*

Codigo C#:

```
[HttpPost(Name = "Login")]
        [Obsolete]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] UserCredentials userCredentials)
        {
            try
            {
                string clientId = _azureActiveDirectorySettings.ClientId;
                string clientSecret = _azureActiveDirectorySettings.ClientSecret;
                string tenantId = _azureActiveDirectorySettings.TenantId;

                string authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}";

                var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);

                var clientCredential = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);

                var userAssertion = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.UserAssertion(userCredentials.Password, "password", userCredentials.Email);

                var result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://outlook.office365.com", clientCredential, userAssertion);

                return Ok(new { AccessToken = result.AccessToken });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return BadRequest(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Si te interesa y es posible usar SSO, prueba [MSAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-overview) en el frontend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puede ser algo relacionado con el ROPC ya que tiene bastantes limitaciones y parece que este puede ser uno de ellos, por lo que no se recomienda en todos los escenarios.

A continuación te dejo las ligeras modificaciones que he hecho a tu código.

```
[HttpPost(Name = "Login")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] UserCredentials userCredentials)
{
    try
    {
        string clientId = _azureActiveDirectorySettings.ClientId;
        string clientSecret = _azureActiveDirectorySettings.ClientSecret;
        string tenantId = _azureActiveDirectorySettings.TenantId;

        string authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}";

        // Use the Microsoft.Identity.Client library instead of Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory
        var app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
            .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
            .WithAuthority(new Uri(authority))
            .Build();

        // In this part you have to be much more specific
        string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://outlook.office365.com/.default" };

        // Acquire token using username and password
        var result = await app.AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword(scopes, userCredentials.Email, new NetworkCredential("", userCredentials.Password).SecurePassword)
                              .ExecuteAsync();

        return Ok(new { AccessToken = result.AccessToken });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return BadRequest(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

En el código que te acabo de dar, he añadido comentarios de lo que he cambiado respecto a tu código.

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Dice que no existe este metodo : AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword

Comment: También me dice que no existe el método AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword , sabes a que se debe?